# How to use Spherical Coordinates to define an area.

Tags: calculus, analysis, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, parametrization

Let $G=\{ (x,y,z) : x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 4 \text{ and } x^2+y^2 \geq 1\}.  $

Use spherical coordinates to describe the area $G$.

---

I imagine that this describes the area in between the sphere with radius 4 and the cylinder of radius 1 but I don't know if that is correct or how to do that. Any hints?

Comment: $$G=\{(r,\theta,\phi): \csc{(\theta)}\le r\le2\}$$

Comment: could you elaborate, please? I don't follow exactly why that would be the case.

Comment: Using spherical coordinates the first inequality is exactly $r^2\le4\iff r\le2$ and the second is $r^2\sin^2{(\theta)}\ge1\iff r\ge\csc{(\theta)}$.

Comment: In this context $x^2+y^2<1$ is actually the interior of  an infinitely-extended-in-both-directions cylinder, with one circular cross-section for each value of $z$. When you say you want $G$'s area, do you mean surface area or volume?

Comment: @J.G. I wish it was clear but the exercise I was given does not specify but I would guess they mean surface.

Comment: @PeterForeman, thank you but what about θ ?

Comment: @Sofia $r$ is positive for definition so you have an implicit inequality $0<csc\theta \le r \le 2$.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use sperical coordinates.

You have to introduce three new variables $\rho,\psi$ and $\theta$ in order to get a new set $G\star$ to do the integration or, as your exercise, to give an other description of an area/volume.
These variables are such that $(\rho,\theta,\psi)\in(0,+\infty)\times(0,\pi)\times(0,2\pi)$.
Now we have to do this change of variables: \begin{cases} x=\rho \sin\theta\cos\psi \\ y=\rho \sin\theta\sin\psi \\ z=\rho\cos\theta \end{cases}

If you now substitute these new coordinates in your initial conditions that define your set $G$, you can easily find the new set $G\star$ which depens from $\rho,\theta$ and $\psi$.

If you have to integrate a volume or calculate the integral of a function in three variables, don't forget the absolute value of the determinat of the Jacobian matrix of the transformation $|\mathrm{det}(J_T)|=\rho^2\sin\theta$.

So, you have this relation between the "old" and the "new" differential: $\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z=|\mathrm{det}(J_T)|\mathrm{d}\rho\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\psi=\rho^2\sin\theta\mathrm{d}\rho\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\psi$.

If you have other difficulties let me know it.